# How to create an IAM policy for Cloudformation, which is based on a stack state?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I'm trying to create an IAM policy to allow deletion of Cloudformation stacks that are in `ROLLBACK_COMPLETE` state ?

Is there any way to achieve a such filter ?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, as far as I can see, it's not possible. I don't see a way to apply a condition to only allow deletion based on stack state.

Documentation on Condition Keys for AWS CloudFormation: [Actions, Resources, and Condition Keys for AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_awscloudformation.html#awscloudformation-policy-keys)

Maybe there's another way to do what you're trying to achieve?